# Google Vision API for reading labels off of an image doesn't give results as accurate as Google Image Search

Tags: google-image-search, google-cloud-vision

I'm looking to create an app that uses an image uploaded by a user and looks for same/similar images on the web. Google images is the best example of that so I tried using the Vision API to first read the image labels and query them using Google Custom Search API.
The issue is, the label reading API doesn't give specific labels. For example, If I upload a starbucks logo on google images, I would get labels "starbucks" and "logo". Using the same image to get labels from the API gives me all other irrelevant labels such as "font", "circle", "art" etc. 
My question is, how come an API by the same company that uses a functionality on their website is giving me different results when I use it?